# Why is my jquery callback firing early?

Tags: jquery, animation, callback

Even with `.promise().done()` my callback function fires early..

**Why?**

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fnSU2/)

```
title.delay(1000).show(1200).promise().done( function(){
  menu.show(0, function(){
    menu.find('*').show(600, message())
  })      
})  

message = function(){ alert('done'); }
```

Comment: `show(600, message())` should be `show(600, message)`

Comment: Why does that make/break it? If I had variables I needed to pass I'd need `()` after the function, so why does it affect it?

Comment: @kcdwayne because you're calling `message` immediately, not passing it as a callback to `.show()`.

Comment: If you had variables you needed to pass, you would create an anonymous function that contains the call to message.

Comment: Hmm.. interesting. Thanks!

Comment: Whenever you put `()` after a function reference, you are *calling* that function. Simple example: `foo(bar())`. `bar` is called first and its return value is passed to `foo`. If you had `foo(bar)`, you'd pass `bar` itself to `foo` (functions are first-class objects). Learn more about functions: http://eloquentjavascript.net/chapter3.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This code:

```
menu.find('*').show(600, message())
```

Needs to be:

```
menu.find('*').show(600, message)
```

The difference is: in the first example you effectively pass two arguments:

1. `600`
2. result that is returned by function `message` (which is `undefined` here)

Because `()` - is the operator to *call* function in JavaScript.

In the second example, however, you pass `600` and *function* `message`.

As @FakeRainBrigand noted - if you want to supply arguments to the function - you have several ways:

1. Use `message = message.bind(<context>, param1, param2,...)`. Then any time you call `message` it will be called with `<context>` as `this` and `param*` as arguments.
2. Use wrapping function:

```
.show(600, function() {
   message(param1, param2, ...);
});
```

Comment: You may want to mention how `message.bind(this, param1, param2)` will allow parameters to be passed to the message.

Comment: It took a second to wrap around what you said but I get it now. It's already being *called* but by simply putting message, the function is simply "performed" when it is queued by the *existing call*. Thanks for the help all!